# Open webpage Decrease Progressively in iMacros browser, help pls

Tags: imacros

I am new to iMacros and I try to write my first scripts ,here is what I write this script to do:
I just setup a new blog and I check all the post everyday,the page link is in format: web.com/viewnews-98.htm ,I need iMacros to open all the posts one by one with 4 secends interval each start frome page 1 increase progressively or from 98 decrease progressively ,I can only write the below part of the scripts, pls show me how to make my first script runing as my wish.

Thanks !

Here is my code:

`VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !VAR1 98
ADD !VAR1 -1
URL GOTO=www.web.com/viewnews-{{!VAR1}}.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this running it with loop

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379 
TAB T=1 
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
SET !VAR1 98 
ADD !VAR1 -{{!loop}} 
URL GOTO=http://www.web.com/viewnews-{{!VAR1}}.html
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but not work,the url will be changed in to:http://www.web.com/viewnews-98-%7B%7B!VAR1%7D%7D.htm

Comment: did you run it with play(loop)?

Comment: yes,the {{!VAR1}} will not be changed into numbers and the url can not be open when I click run loop.